# [Vis.js]How to use storePositions()

Tags: typescript, vis.js

I want to know how to use the function storePositions of the dataView library Vis.js. And I want to know if there is a forum for this library(I don't found it)
Thanks for you help !

There is no documention about it, no one ask for this.
I have already try something for storing positions but I'm beginner in development. Here is my try

```js
    let positions = network.getPositions();
    let nodesO = this.objectToArray(positions);
    let store = network.storePositions(nodesO);
    console.log(nodesO);
    console.log(store);
  }
```

I need to store the positions of my nodes when they are moved.

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation for this method on https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#methods , just search for storePositions.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by explicit.

Comment: I mean isn't explained on their website !

Comment: storePositions returns nothing, so where the data goes?

Comment: It's saved into the objects stored in the node data set (`new Network(container, { nodes: new DataSet([/*some nodes*/]) });`). I don't think it has any noticeable effect if you simply shoved there (`new Network(container, { nodes: [/*some nodes*/] });`) an array though.

Answer (score 1):

Although @tomáš-vyčítal, a member of visjs, answered it and it makes sense, but an example would be helpful, because 'stablization' part on document makes it losing focused.

```
> data.nodes.get(1)
{id: 1, label: 'Node 1'}
> network.storePositions()
undefined
> data.nodes.get(1)
{id: 1, label: 'Node 1', x: 52, y: 81}
```

This would be useful to save/restore positions of all nodes from/to a database

```
> JSON.stringify(data.nodes.get())
'[{"id":1,"label":"Node 1"},{"id":2,"label":"Node 2"},{"id":3,"label":"Node 3"},{"id":4,"label":"Node 4"},{"id":5,"label":"Node 5"}]'
> network.storePositions()
undefined
> JSON.stringify(data.nodes.get())
'[{"id":1,"label":"Node 1","x":-61,"y":-80},{"id":2,"label":"Node 2","x":15,"y":11},{"id":3,"label":"Node 3","x":-160,"y":-152},{"id":4,"label":"Node 4","x":-35,"y":126},{"id":5,"label":"Node 5","x":142,"y":-3}]'
```

You may try this in console from this url.
https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/basicUsage.html